# Why do class properties need comments

Tags: c#

StyleCop uses the `Gets or Sets ...` notation which it enforces with rule [SA1623](http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/SA1623.html)

My question is why, as from what I can see the vast majority of the time it is self explanatory and requires lots of repetition to have these?

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the name of the customer
/// </summary>
public string Name { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets whether the record is archived
/// </summary>
public string IsArchive{ get; set; }
```

It can also make it overly verbose, when you have just 10 lines, each one declaring a property, you end up with 30+ lines to have a summary comment on each!

Comment: StyleCop isn't always right.  If you feel a particular rule isn't helpful for you or your team, disable it.

Comment: It's worth noting: the xml comments are very useful if you are building a publicly exposed API library and want to document your code in such a way as MSDN documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302121.aspx.  Projects like SandCastle can be used to create very complete documentation of your code based upon your XML comments: http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/.

Comment: @JoeBrunscheon Many documentation generators for various languages will still generate skeleton documentation for class members even without comments. Does the part that generates documentation for properties in C# not mark read/write/readwrite automatically without needing it to be explicitly specified by the code writer?

Comment: @JAB Most of the documentation generators are pretty configurable. However, I can't really answer your question as it would be entirely dependent upon the doc generator you use. As I recall, SandCastle automatically documents properties with stub documentation for properties without comments.

Comment: I haven't used it in a while, but GhostDoc is a tool that can automatically generate simple comments inferred from the identifiers in your code.  So, I think a simple comment like "Gets or sets the name of the customer" is something like what it would produce.  I recommend caution, though, not to rely on it so much that you don't write any comments yourself, because of course it cannot properly comment something that is complicated or poorly named.

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice Does GhostDoc generate them in separate documentation or actually in the code file?

Comment: @CodeBlend in the code file as normal XML comments, like the ones in the code example above. It does other elements as well, not just the summary, in the case of methods or classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

StyleCop rules are not absolutes but instead guidelines.  In general this is a good rule but in some cases yes the properties are simple enough that documentation is probably overkill.  For example

```
class Student { 
  public string FirstName { get; set; } 
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

A comment on these properties really adds no value as are pretty self descriptive.

I'm a big fan of using StyleCop in projects.  But that doesn't mean you have to take every single rule it comes with.  Disable the ones that don't make sense for your project and embrace the ones that do

Answer (score 4):

For completeness of documentation for publicly accessible members?

Comment: Actually having it as a rule seems excessive to me as most of the classes I come across are as in my example, self-explanatory. It can also make it overly verbose, when you have just 10 lines, each one declaring a property, you end up with 30+ lines to have a summary comment on each!

Comment: Maybe what would be better as a company guideline would be priority of correctly named properties (FirstName not Name) and then a summary, if necessary

Answer (score 2):

It isn't necessary. From my point of view it's self-explanatory like you said.

If the variables have useful names, then it is a waste of time to write something like that.

If there are variables, which aren't self-explanatory, then such comments would be useful (e.g. some old code?)

Answer (score 1):

Due to my job's code standards I'm obligated to write those kinds of comments. To me it's not necessary to add a comment to a property when its name reveals its purpose.

The main issues with that approach are the waste of time commenting and the fact that the comment itself is unhelpful. Most of the time it's just repeating the property's name.

PS: My point of view only applies when the property name reveals its purpose. There are several cases where commenting is highly recommended.